# Centroids of a shape file

Tags: r, shapefile

I've created a shapefile by fusing polygons using `unionSpatialPolygons`, how can I find out the coordinates of the new polygons which have been created?

Comment: I remember that objects of class `spatial.polygons` had a `coordinates` method. Have you tried `coordinates(yourObject)`?

Comment: Can you provide the result of `class(yourObject)`?

Comment: coordinates(my.object) indeed returns the centroids of each polygon. Many thanks.

Comment: Ummm.... Do you really mean centroid, or just vertex coordinates?  You seem to be mixing the terms here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options, depending on which kind of centroid you want to calculate.  I took these algorithms from some wikipedia pages.

```
# polyx and polyy are the x and y coordinates of the polygon vertices 
# notice had to negate these calcs in final line...
 require(pracma,quietly=TRUE)

pchit <- polyarea(polyx,polyy)
    centx <- centy <- 0
    for (kk in 1:(length(polyx)-1) ) {
        centx <- centx + (polyx[kk]+polyx[kk+1]) * (polyx[kk]*polyy[kk+1]-polyx[kk+1]*polyy[kk])
        centy <- centy + (polyy[kk]+polyy[kk+1]) * (polyx[kk]*polyy[kk+1]-polyx[kk+1]*polyy[kk])
    }
    centx <- -1/pchit/6 * centx
    centy <- -1/pchit/6 * centy
    #  These next two are for vertex centroid, rather than polygon centroid
    # centx <- mean(polyx)
    # centy <- mean(polyy)
```